# In dplyr filter rows with number of NA bigger than one

Tags: r, dplyr

This is my code:

```
airquality %>% filter(across(everything(), ~ sum(is.na(.x)) > 1))
```

I am trying to filter the rows with more than one NAs.

The only way I achieve this was using `mutate` function.

```
airquality %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(n_NA = sum(is.na(across(everything())))) %>%
                  filter(n_NA > 1)
```

But its not a clever way.

I need to **use only `filter` function.**

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` to create a logical expression within `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
airquality  %>% 
    filter(rowSums(is.na(.)) > 1)
```

-output

```
#   Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
#1    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
#2    NA      NA  8.0   57     5  27
```

---

Or with `rowwise` and `c_across`

```
airquality %>%
   rowwise %>%
   filter(sum(is.na(c_across(everything()))) > 1)
# A tibble: 2 x 6
# Rowwise: 
#  Ozone Solar.R  Wind  Temp Month   Day
#  <int>   <int> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
#1    NA      NA  14.3    56     5     5
#2    NA      NA   8      57     5    27
```

Comment: You are  always helping us. Thanks for your time @akrun!